# Rust newbie compile error (for (key: String, value: String) in | ^ expected one of `)`, `,`, `@`, or `|`)

Tags: string, rust, compilation

I just read through the first three chapters of the Rust Programming Language, and am currently trying to apply my limited knowledge building a CLI weather app with the help of a YouTube tutorial.

I mostly have little idea what I'm doing, but just wanted to make something to inspire learning momentum.

May someone share some explanations on what I did wrong?

I tried compiling Rust code and failed with a syntax error.

```
fn main() {
    for (x: String, ) in [("hello".into(),)] {}
}
```

```
error: expected one of `)`, `,`, `@`, or `|`, found `:`
 --> src/main.rs:2:11
  |
2 |     for (x: String, ) in [("hello".into(),)] {}
  |           ^ expected one of `)`, `,`, `@`, or `|`

error: could not compile `forecast` (bin "forecast") due to 1 previous error
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=25d538c8684b388a265367075881e742)

Comment: You don't need, and can't, have type ascription inside patterns.

Answer (score 0):

> May someone share some explanations on what I did wrong?

As Ivan C commented, you can't have types *inside* patterns, [which is why the left hand side of a `for` is](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#iterator-loops). Nor does `for` support type annotations (as you can see -- or not see -- in the link above), so if you update the code to what you'd find in a `let` for instance:

```rust
for (x,): (String,) in [("hello".into(),)] {}
```

you will get

```
  |
2 |     for (x,): (String,) in [("hello".into(),)] {}
  |             ^ --------- specifying the type of a pattern isn't supported
```

There are two solutions to this:

1. ensure the value is typed, instead of using `"hello".into()` you can use `String::from("hello")` or `"hello".to_string()`, that will ensure the value is correctly typed and solve the issue
2. use iterators, as those take functions, which can be typed:

   ```rust
   [("hello".into(),)].into_iter().for_each(|(x,): (String,)| {})
   ```

I would personally recommend the former.

Or really you could just iterate on the `&str` themselves, it works fine, and only convert to a `String` if ans where needed.